# PHP syntax output wrong string

Tags: php, syntax

```
echo "<td><a href='#'>Edit</a> | <a href='javascript:delpost('".$cat2['id']."','".$cat2['name']."')'>Delete</a></td>";
```

This PHP code will output this:

```
<a href="javascript:delpost(" 85','a)'>Delete</a>
```

But I want this:

```
<a href="javascript:delpost('85','a')">Delete</a>
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: What does `var_dump($cat2);` show?

Comment: You shouldn't walk away from your question as you have comments that need answering and the window to get a good answer is closing.

Comment: Sorry about that my late answers. Its show sql query row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mixed up the quotes. Try this:

```
echo '<td><a href="#">Edit</a> | <a href="javascript:delpost(\'' . $cat2['id'] . '\',\'' . $cat2['name'] . '\')">Delete</a></td>';
```

See output here: https://3v4l.org/qpeM6.

Note: this code assumes `id` is an integer or a string without any leading spaces, and `name` should be a string without leading spaces. If there are spaces in the values, you can wrap the values like this `trim($cat2['id'])`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @OptimusCrime. Its working.

Answer (score 0):

You could use do this.  Use single quotes instead of double quotes, escaping out the others.

```
 echo '<td><a href=\'#\'>Edit</a> | <a href="javascript:delpost(\''.$test1.'\',\''.$test1.'\')">Delete</a></td>';
```

Comment: This works fine, too. Thank you @PeteyHowell